# MySql Replication - Master as slave and slave as master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a setup were Master and slave are running, I want to do the cut over the process to make the Slave as master and stop the old master.

So I want to know the process which should be followed.

Thank you Advance.

Comment: I would need to understand more about the particular situation. What kind of processes currently access the (current) master system? Which ones may make updates or inserts? Can they be shut down or disabled during the switchover? Is it OK for there to be some downtime?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about instances of mysql acting as slaves.  They are exactly the same as the master in every respect - they just read a binary log file to perform the same updates as the master.  This is why it so easy to break replication - because you can insert data directly in the slave that will cause problems - but that's going off this topic.

Now, assuming your slave is left entirely alone and all reads and writes happen on the master, switching is simply a case of re configuring the application to use the slaves authentication details.  All reads and writes will then happen on the slave directly instead of happening on the master and be reproduced on the slave via the binlog.

To prevent any updates on the "old" master from coming through to the slave stop the slave thread running.  This is literally as simple as typing "stop slave;" on the slaves command line.

You should then clear any configuration in the slave that tells it to connect to the old master as such a re connection would be very dangerous due to the risk of primary key clashes.

Comment: Something to check: A slave will usually be configured as read-only, which needs to be disabled before switching the master.

Comment: Usually is a little strong as there are many pitfalls with this configuration, but it is worth checking.

It's probably also worth checking that the user has insert and update privilages in the schema as this is another, arguably more controllable, way of ensuring application users can not write to a slave.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. Replace "usually" with "in the extremely unusual case of a properly configured slave". Anyway, if you simulate "(super_)read_only" by changing user permissions/disabling root/..., then you need to check and undo that instead. In any case,  ̶m̶o̶s̶t̶ some slaves will have some kind of protection in that regard, so it should be included in your answer (for the unlikely case someone actually did use protection).